# How to get fully qualified assembly name

Tags: c#

is there any easy way to get the fully qualified name for assembbly? e.g.

```
<section name="unity" type=" Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=2.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve an assembly's qualified type name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441680/how-can-i-retrieve-an-assemblys-qualified-type-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the fully qualified name of an assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658446/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-name-of-an-assembly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb.aspx) article (How to: Determine an Assembly's Fully Qualified Name
) will probably help you

---

Code from MSDN

```
//s if the Fully Qualified assembly name
Type t = typeof(System.Data.DataSet);
string s = t.Assembly.FullName.ToString();
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a shameless copy-paste from [I Note It Down](http://inoteitdown.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/get-assembly-fully-qualified-name.html) and is a simple way to get the FQAN for the project output:

```
Open Visual Studio
Go to Tools –> External Tools –> Add
    Title: Get Qualified Assembly Name
    Command: Powershell.exe
    Arguments: -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName(\"$(TargetPath)\").FullName"
    Check "Use Output Window".
```

The new tool appears under `Tools –> Get Qualified Assembly Name`. When the menu item is selected, the assembly name is given in the output window.